# SKAction moveTo:duration: does not respond correctly on CGPoint value of the touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I am using SpriteKit for building a game , where I have a plane, which I want to move on touch. The idea is to relocate the plane to the position where the user has touched.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGPoint moveToLocation = point;

SKAction *planeMove = [SKAction moveTo:moveToLocation duration:0.5];

[_plane runAction:planeMove]; // _plane represents the plane sprite.


NSLog(@"Touch Point: %@ ",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
NSLog(@"Plane Location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(_plane.position));
```

The above code gives undesired result with different values for Touch Point and Plane Location. Hence, the plane after the touch is far away from the point where it is desired to be.
For example, the values I get in NSLog:

```
Touch Point: {391, 743}
Location: {393, 672}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your second line to

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInNode:self];
```